# Is it safe to "include" text files?

Tags: php, include

I have been including `.txt` files in my php files so that I can easily maintain and re-use blocks of code (the `.txt` file containing the block). For example:

```
if (!$Correct)
    {
       include ("block.txt");
    }
```

The blocks of code usually include additional HTML and PHP to define menus, contents blocks, etc., and often include lines within them to open database connections. Is this a safe practice? Is it open to attack? Can anyone suggest some best practices for this type of include?

Comment: just as long as you hide/protect it using `.htaccess` and possibly placed outside the public domain, sure.

Comment: This is the first time I have heard of .htaccess. Could someone point me to a how-to-guide for hide/protecting these files?

Comment: why not .php? then the content is safe from the web-end

Comment: "why not .php?" - Absolutely no reason, other than I inherited some code that did this. Would including .php include the code inline? Is that the safest way to go?